# How can I have different content for different countries?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, categories, customization

My company has always served the Australian market, but we are now also working in the US. How can I have a US version of the site with some different pages/content, without having multiple installations of wordpress? Although some content will need to be different, a lot will remain the same.

I don't need the content to load dynamically based on IP, I would rather they just click a link for their region.

Comment: Use the multisite feature of the core and the features of the plugin MultilingualPress http://multilingualpress.pro

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved in two ways:

1. By creating a multiregion website
2. By creating a multilingual website

Option #1 will need to detect the visitor/user's country based on his IP and then the content will be served. However, as you have mentioned that you do not want to do that, the option for you is #2.

You can create multilingual WordPress site by using a plugin like [WPML](https://wpml.org/). It allows you to create separate content for different languages. Currently you are working for Australian market and expanding to US market. Though the language in both countries is English, in future you may expand to some other countries which have different languages where [WPML](https://wpml.org/) would play a crucial role. WPML will allow you to create subdirectory or subdomain option for different language sites.

In case of subdirectory your URLs would be:

1. http://example.com/au/
2. http://example.com/us/

In case of subdomain your URLs would be:

1. http://au.example.com/
2. http://us.example.com/

So in my opinion that would be the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. If I decided to go the "multiregion website" route, how would you recommend doing that? Is there a plugin that achieves that?